# Can I split a text in Python from certain words?

Tags: python

I want to try splitting the text since a certain word to a certain word

For example
"I have an apple and I want to eat it.
If we splt the sentence from the word "I", it would become like this:
#["I have an apple and", "I want to eat it"]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
phrase = "I have an apple and I want to eat it."
word = "I"
split = phrase.split(word) # ["", " have an apple and ", " want to eat it."]
split = [word + part for part in split if part] # ["I have an apple and ", "I want to eat it."]
```